# How to convince emacs to interpret string of any characters as string

Tags: string

I want to insert this template:
<< prints("on_%s.gd:"%name, "msg: %s"%msg); >>
How to convince emacs it's a string?

Comment: It's not clear to me -- at all -- what you're asking. What do you mean by *"convince emacs"* that this is a string: `<< prints("on_%s.gd:"%name, "msg: %s"%msg); >>`? Where does that text occur? Out of the blue (no context), that text **isn't** a string. And a string in what programming language? And what do you mean by *"template"*, here? I find *nothing* about your question to be at all comprehensible; sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this:

```
(insert "<< prints(\"on_%s.gd:\"%name, \"msg: %s\"%msg); >>")
```

in the `*Scratch*` buffer to see it inserting:

```
<< prints("on_%s.gd:"%name, "msg: %s"%msg); >>
```

Use:

```
(message "<< prints(\"on_%s.gd:\"%%name, \"msg: %s\"%%msg); >>" "EVENT" "MESSAGE")
```

to get:

```
"<< prints(\"on_EVENT.gd:\"%name, \"msg: MESSAGE\"%msg); >>"
```

*Notice that in the first case you need only to escape the quotation marks with a backslash `\`* where **in the second case it is in addition to that also necessary to escape the percent `%` sign by doubling it in order to get a `%` in the output.**

FINALLY:

```
(insert (message "<< prints(\"on_%s.gd:\"%%name, \"msg: %s\"%%msg); >>" "EVENT" "MESSAGE"))
```

will give you:

```
<< prints("on_EVENT.gd:"%name, "msg: MESSAGE"%msg); >>
```

After you have got the idea how it works, you can also escape the `%s` with `%%s` instead of using it to inject values into the output string in the `(message` statement, but I suppose this is not what you are asking for.